# Complex disabled in Add Function import in edmx

Tags: edmx

The Complex radio button is disabled in add function import in edmx. Due to this i'm not able to set the return type as Complex.

How can i enable it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you are using Visual Studio 2010 and EFv1 = .NET 3.5 SP1 where returning complex types is not supported. It is new feature in EFv4 = .NET 4.0